# How do I install gcc 10.2 with sudo apt-get install gcc-x g++-x?

Tags: gcc, g++

I was able to install gcc 10 but I need 10.2 not 10 and it keeps telling me gcc10.2 does not exist, well it does and I tried installing it by compiling and building it in the command line however that did not seem to install it or make my system recognize its existence in any way.

`sudo apt-get install gcc-10 g++-10` works.

`sudo apt-get install gcc-10.2 g++-10.2` does not

Comment: Install the compiled binary on your $PATH. Try `echo $PATH` to see which filesystem locations are appropriate. Somewhere in /usr/local is best for locally-compiled binaries. 10.2 has not been packaged yet by Debian, and the next release of Ubuntu (20.10) will use 10.1.

Comment: I added it to my path in .bashrc @user535733

Comment: How do I install it to my path? @user535733

Comment: I went to /user/local and gcc10.2 is already there.

Comment: Trying to configure it as an alternative but when I do gcc --version becomes unrecognized command until I switch back to gcc 10.

Answer (score 9):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++-10
```

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the version used in [this article](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/) with mine and installed to `/usr/loacl/bin` instead.

Then I needed to update the gcc alternatives [as shown here](https://tuxamito.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_newer_GCC_versions_in_Ubuntu). I replaced this version with mine. I used `/usr/local/bin/gcc-10.2.0/bin/gcc-10.2` to use the executable instead of the folder. It's currently working for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.